# How do I convert a date string containing 7 digits in milliseconds into a date in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

When the milliseonds have 6 digits, %f works, but it throws an error if there are more than 6 digits. I have a temporary solution by hardcoding a 0 for the 7th digit, but is there a better way to do? Currently the below works

```
print (datetime.datetime.strptime(('2014-11-19 00:00:00.0000000').strip(), '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S.0%f')).date()
```

Comment: Why not just trim if it's `0`?

Comment: This limitation is documented in datetime doc. I suggest you use the `arrow` library : http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation of `datetime.strptime()` https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior, technical note (4), %f accepts only 1 - 6 chars:

> %f is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard
>   (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always
>   available). When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive
>   accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right.

I do NOT believe you have solved the problem correctly. You should not prefix the string with zero, but instead drop everything past 6 (which is less significant to contributing to time).

Something like this:

```
s='2014-11-19 00:00:00.0000000'
print (datetime.datetime.strptime((s[:26]).strip(), '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S.%f')).date()
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Just another doubt, what does [:26] refer to here?

Comment: You provided a 27 character date string. The s[:26] trims it to 26 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the date, only extract the date!

```
>>> datetime_string = '2014-11-19 00:00:00.0000000'
>>> date_string = datetime_string[:10]
>>> date_string
'2014-11-19'
>>> print(datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')).date()
2014-11-19
```

Answer (score 0):

I think solution in comment #1 is ok but needs some correction,

Use it like below,

```
s='2014-11-19      00:00:00.0000000'
print (datetime.datetime.strptime(s.strip()).[:26], '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S.%f')).date()
```

It will remove all spaces then take 26 characters from start of string, and passes to to strptime() method.