# How to convert this string in python

Tags: python, datetime

2018-02-06T14:45:03.0040554Z

Unable to convert this string to datetime.

`datetime.strptime('2018-02-06T14:45:03.0040554Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ')`

I am trying this and it doesn't work.

`datetime.strptime('2018-02-06T14:45:03Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ')`

This work for above time format.

But I'm getting this time string from third party api so can't change its format.

Comment: 0040554 has 7 digits. $f match 6 digits.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use the **[dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.6.1)** module you can do this.

```
from dateutil import parser
print parser.parse('2018-02-06T14:45:03.0040554Z')
```

**Output:**

```
2018-02-06 14:45:03.004055+00:00
```

Using Datetime. Looks like you missed the seconds param and the microseconds need to be 6 you have 7.

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-02-06T14:45:03.004055Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-02-06T14:45:03Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

**Output**:

```
2018-02-06 14:45:03.004055
2018-02-06 14:45:03
```

Comment: datetime won't work, because `%f` stands for microseconds (up to 6 digits) and @Yawar has 7 digits after the dot. You deleted `4` right before `Z`.

Comment: @BUZZY. You are right I forgot to add that info in the description.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime('2018-02-06T14:45:03.0040554Z').to_pydatetime()

'2018-02-06 14:45:03.004055'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input format is super-strange, as it has 7 digits in second fraction

Take a look at old question: [How do I convert a date string containing 7 digits in milliseconds into a date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783222/how-do-i-convert-a-date-string-containing-7-digits-in-milliseconds-into-a-date-i)

You can either split/rejoin string and use `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'` or use `dateutil.parser.parse`

Comment: office365 api is returning this super-strange format :(